# linear functions on the space on continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)=(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$, and consider the
>   functional $$F_1\colon X \to \mathbb{R}; \quad f \mapsto \int^{\frac{3}{4}}_{\frac{1}{2}}f(t)\,dt.$$ Show that $F_1$ is a
>   continuous linear functional and find $\|F_1\|_{X^*}$.

I am lost with the first question. I am trying to show that it is continuous at $f=0$, which proves that it is continuous to for all points on $C[0,1]$.

For the last question, I have gotten one quarter, but I think my methods may be wrong. Help!

Comment: You may just show that $F_1$ is bounded: $\| F_1(f)\| \le C\| f\|_\infty$ for some $C$. For the second question, your answer is correct so I cannot tell why you think you are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $F_1$ is a linear map (this follows easily by checking $F_1(f + \alpha g)=F_1(f)+\alpha F_1(g)$ for any $f,g \in X$ and any scalar $\alpha$). Thus, to show that it is continuous it suffices to show that it is bounded (why?). Next, for any $f \in X$ we have 
$$
\left|F_1(f) \right| = \left|\int_{1/2}^{3/4} f(t) \ dt\right|  \leq  \int_{1/2}^{3/4} |f(t)| \ dt \leq \|f\|_\infty\int_{1/2}^{3/4} 1 \ dt=\frac{1}{4}\|f\|_\infty 
$$
This proves that $\|F_1\|_{X^*} \leq 1/4$ (why?) and therefore that $F_1$ is indeed a bounded linear map. Further, now you only need to show that $\|F_1\|_{X^*} \geq 1/4$ (how would you do this?) to get that $\|F_1\|_{X^*} = 1/4$. Since you are not showing your methods, I cannot tell if they are wrong or right.

Comment: thank you so much! my method for the second part was the same as yours :)

Comment: You are welcome Catherine!